# Android FragmentManager Listeners

Tags: java, android

While searching for the best way to store and notify listeners (weak references vs strong references, anonymous listeners vs garbage collector), I took a look at how Google implement their listeners. The following code codes from the FragmentManager class:

```
ArrayList<OnBackStackChangedListener> mBackStackChangeListeners;

public void removeOnBackStackChangedListener(OnBackStackChangedListener listener) {
    if (mBackStackChangeListeners != null) {
        mBackStackChangeListeners.remove(listener);
    }
}

void reportBackStackChanged() {
    if (mBackStackChangeListeners != null) {
        for (int i=0; i<mBackStackChangeListeners.size(); i++) {
           mBackStackChangeListeners.get(i).onBackStackChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

If there is a listener removed in its `onBackStackChanged`, something like:

```
@Override
void onBackStackChanged()
{
    mFragmentManager.removeOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
}
```

It seems to me that the next listener in the ArrayList will be skipped.

Am I missing something? Is this something that is not supposed to be done?